# Return a generic type of another generic type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, automapper

I have a custom Enum class:

```
public abstract class Enum<T> where T : struct, IComparable
{
    public T Id { get; }

    public string Value { get; }
    
    protected Enum(T id, string @value)
    {
        Id = id;
        Value = @value;
    }
}
```

And another class which inherits from this class:

```
public sealed class Status : Enum<byte>
{
    public static readonly Status Pending = new Status(0, "PENDING");
    public static readonly Status Finished = new Status(1, "FINISHED");
    
    private Status(byte id, string name) : base(id, name)
    {
    }
    
    public static Status Create (string @value)
    {
        // some logic here
        //return Wrapper.Wrap(Finished);
        return Finished;
    }
    
    public static Wrapper<Status> CreateWrapper(string @value)
    {
        // some logic here
        return Wrapper.Wrap(Finished);
    }
}
```

Now I want to make a custom type converter in AutoMapper and these following converters work fine:

```
public class StatusConverter<TType> : ITypeConverter<string, Enum<byte>>
{
    public Enum<byte> Convert(string source, Enum<byte> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return Status.Create(source);
    }
}

public class StatusConverter2<TValue> : ITypeConverter<string, Wrapper<Status>> // works fine
{
    public Wrapper<Status> Convert(string source, Wrapper<Status> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return Status.CreateWrapper(source);
    }
}
```

Now I created a new Wrapper class:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public static Wrapper<T> Wrap<T>(T @value)
    {
        return new Wrapper<T>(@value);
    }
}

public class Wrapper<T>
{
    T Value;
    
    internal Wrapper(T @value)
    {
        Value = @value;
    }
}
```

And I want to do the following:

```
public class StatusConverter3<TValue> : ITypeConverter<string, Wrapper<Enum<byte>>> // doesn't work with Enum<T>
{
    public Wrapper<Enum<byte>> Convert(string source, Wrapper<Enum<byte>> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return Status.CreateWrapper(source);
    }
}
```

I want to create a generic type converter, but I get an error that I cannot implicitly convert from `Wrapper<Status>` to `Wrapper<Enum<byte>>`.

Here is a dotnetfiddle demo of my problem:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/xM9JVg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Covariant generic modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier)

1. Introduce an interface

   ```
   public interface IWrapper<out T> 
   { 
   }
   ```
2. Implement it on your Wrapper

   ```
   Wrapper<T> : IWrapper<T>
   ```
3. Use the interface in your converters instead of a class

   ```
   public class StatusConverter3<TValue> : ITypeConverter<string, IWrapper<Enum<byte>>>
   ```

Be aware that in this case your `Wrapper<T>` wouldn't be allowed to have a methods that took `T` as input parameters

Check the [fork](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vNWIeg)

Comment: Damn, that's very smart. I usually get recommendations from the IDE to use `in` and `out` in my interfaces, but I never truly understood the purpose of them. This challenge has made me understand it more. Thank you very much!